# How to check if there is an element at the specific index in a list?

Tags: c#, list

How to check if there is an element at the specific index in a list, like

```
Product[i]
```

Is it there or not? How to write this check?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `i` is the index you want to have, check the `Count`:

```
if (i >= 0 && (list.Count - 1) >= i)
{
    // okay, the item is there
}
```

If talking about nullable types, you could also check if the item on that index isn't `null`:

```
if (i >= 0 && (list.Count - 1) >= i && list[i] != null)
{
    // okay, the item is there, and it has a value
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try like this

```
if (Product.Contains(yourItem))
   int Index = Array.IndexOf(Product, yourItem);
```

if you want to check that the index is exist in that particular array then you can just check the length of that array.

```
if (i < Product.Length && i > -1)
    //yes it has
```

Comment: That code checks the actual contents of an item in the list, not the index. Also, it is not very efficient for this problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
return (Product.Count() -1) <= i;
```

or if you're feeling hackish:

```
try { var x = Product[i]; return true; } catch(ArrayIndexOutOfBoundException) { return false; }
```

or

```
Product.Skip(i).Any()
```

or...